# Is it possible to train XGBoost4J-Spark with tree_method='exact' ?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, xgboost

I intend to use the trained xgboost model with tree_method='exact' in the SparkML pipeline so I need to use XGBoost4J-Spark; however documentation says "Distributed and external memory version only support approximate algorithm." (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest//parameter.html). Is there anyway to work around this?

Alternatively, I can train the model with C-based xgboost and some how convert the trained model to XGBoostEstimator which is a SparkML estimator and seamless to integrate in SparkML pipeline. Has anyone came across such a convertor?

I don't mind running on a single node instead of a cluster as I can afford to wait.

Any insights is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So there is this way:

```
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.XGBoost
val xgb1 = XGBoost.loadModel("xgb1")
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostRegressionModel
val xgbSpark = new XGBoostRegressionModel(xgb1)
```

where `xgb1` is the model trained with C-based xgboost. There is a problem however; their predictions don't match. I have reported the issue on the github repo: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3190